# Queue Simulation

Tags: java

Hi im trying to simulate a waiting queue by using Java. What my program must consist of:

- The user input nth number of cashiers
- There minimum of 10 customers will arrive in the queue in random intervals.
- When a cashier is free the the next customer is line will be processed.
- The program must output each stage of the queue as well as the time each customer spent in the queue.

Oki so what I have so is a empty queue object, a random string list generator which sends the strings to the queue.

However what problems im having is the random string generator is picking duplicates in the loop, how do I fix this ? 
Also how do I make it send the customers to the queue in intervals of 0.5 sec and I need to record the time they enter the queue and leave the queue so then I can output the time spent in the queue. Im stuck dont know what to do now ?

```
public static Queue<String> line = new  LinkedList<String> ();

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] list = {"a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", };
    int customer = list.length;

    for (int x = 0; x < customer; x++ )
    {
      int cus = (int) (Math.random() * customer);
      line.add(list[cus]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it is, it's random.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a familiar problem: [Producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) and [Thread.sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29).  You should think about a loop where you do work (consume/produce) and then sleep for 500 milliseconds and then continue to loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Oki so far Ive managed to get loop working with outputting the customer name and the time they were served by using methods in another class. However Im still stuck on if the user inputs nth number of cashier which basically mean the whole loop will run x(nth cashier inputted).

```
 Random ran = new Random();
    while (!line.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(line  + "\n");
        System.out.println("The queue has " + line.size() + " customers left");
        Customer cus = line.remove();
        System.out.println(cus.name + " queued at " + cus.getTime() + " <=== SERVED" + "\n");
        // you will have to sleep a random number of seconds here
        int wait = ran.nextInt(2) + 1;  // will generate 1 or 2
        try 
        {
             Thread.sleep(wait * 1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sleep error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The Random function generates a number based on the time executed. Because the for loop is pretty fast the random function generates the same number. Try making a new function with the code in the loop and calling it from the loop.

Comment: This is untrue. Two random number generators from the same seed with generate the same sequence. A random generator _may generate_ the same numbers - it is simply sampling a uniform distribution after all.